# GraphQL - importing typedefs schema for makeExecutableSchema creates unhandled promise

Tags: javascript, promise, graphql

Currently using these 2 boilerplates for a minimal **GraphQL server** with client implementation, connecting over localhost.

https://github.com/apollographql/frontpage-server

https://github.com/apollographql/frontpage-react-app

Upon, editing and splitting out typdefs similar to the apollo docs, I'm unable to make a successful connection to the server when I execute makeExecutableSchema in a different file to the typedef it is using. I'm left hanging in the network with pending.

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import resolvers from './resolvers';
import schema from './data/schema';
const modSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: schema,
  resolvers: resolvers
});
export default modSchema`
```

I get in console:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Must provide schema`

So, typedefs need it to be a string or array. And I presume I need to execute a function somewhere to satisfy the unhandled promise upon attempting to hit the server from my client. This works when the above is in the same file as the typedef it is using (as per the original boilerplate above). How would I achieve this here when moving to the separate file? How is it creating the error?

Comment: nothing in the code you posted would cause that error, as there is no sign of Promises in the code

Comment: I suggest printing the schema in the file where you're importing it. Most likely you're not importing it properly there and it ends up being undefined.